# Task "Update attributes for 34 selected products": 1 item(s) have been scheduled for update

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3

I had done bulk update after that i am getting message like
Task "Update attributes for 34 selected products": 1 item(s) have been scheduled for update.
For reference please find the attached image
[image]

And status is showing like not started
[image]

Comment: are you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Need to start message queue consumers.

After consuming all available messages, the command terminates. You can run the below command again manually or with a cron job

```
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.update --max-messages=20
```

Comment: how to do with cron job ?

Comment: i had used above command line but no response is coming

Comment: Review new answer. How to setup with cron job?

Comment: 30 mins over still not completed, any suggestion, thanks.

Comment: hi any help, 1 day over still not completed