# M2 - commerce edition - Task "Update attributes for 12 selected products": 1 item(s) have been scheduled for update

Tags: magento2.3.4, magento-2-commerce

How to solve this error, product not visible on frontend, one day over still getting this notification.

Comment: Make sure cron running or not.

Comment: How to check my cron is running or not?

Comment: You can check by "crontab -l" command

Comment: If not running then run  "php bin/magento cron:install" and then "php bin/magento cron:run"

Comment: -bash: crontab: command not found  any help?

Comment: i am using windows.

Comment: I don't know regarding windows.

Answer (score 1):

Hi please try to run below command and see if this solves your issue

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```

try this then

```
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.update --max-messages=20
```

**more details here**

[Task "Update attributes for 34 selected products": 1 item(s) have been scheduled for update](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297605/task-update-attributes-for-34-selected-products-1-items-have-been-scheduled)

Comment: Yes i did,  still showing same message on header.

Comment: check the updated ans